# In Rails, I'm trying to pass an attribute to a Model's "new" method, then to the "create method". What's the most efficient way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, variables

In my Rails application I have a Forum with many Topics. From the Forum's, "show" page I have a list of Topics with a link to create a new Topic. My goal is to make sure that when creating the new Topic I have the ID of the Forum when I get to the Topic's "create" method. Right now I'm thinking I'd have to create a hidden field on the Topic's "new" page and set the hidden field to the Forum's ID. I was wondering if there is a better, cleaner way.

Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested resources are the way to go for this, so you nest the `Topic` resource within the `Forum` resource. Take a look at these tutorials:

- [Nested Resources Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)
- [Nested Resources Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources)